# Error on PHP Excel 1.8 Call to undefined function getNameFromNumber()

Tags: php, import, phpexcel

i just wanted to import with PHP Excel 1.8 class and then i got this error Fatal error: Call to undefined function getNameFromNumber() in includes/PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/HTML.php on line 1617.

Can someone image what here the problem or better what i can do?

Thanks.
Olaf

Comment: Where did you get this version of PHPExcel from, because the `getNameFromNumber()` function doesn't exist anywhere in PHPExcel, nor does any part of PHPExcel call this non-existent function

Comment: Hello, i got this script from an indian developer... i now added update, but now there is to less memory (memory exhausted). Do you know, what i can do? provider only gives max of 256MB and that does not work.

Comment: Memory reduction options are well documented in PHPExcel, including options like cell caching.... reading the documentation is always helpful

Comment: Although are you importing or exporting? If you are importing, reading files, then you also have chunked reading, reading only certain worksheets or parts of worksheets, and other options..... but you wouldn't normally be using Writers if you were importing

Comment: We use both... reading for importing and writing for generating HTML page

Comment: Certainly take a look at [cell caching](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/04-Configuration-Settings.md) for reducing the memory footprint

Comment: ah perfect! ok. we are importing data for later saving in db. but in the same file there is also a second PHPExel func step, where we write to HTML before import goes further. Or is this the problem?

Comment: The problem is that loading large files into memory takes memory; while PHPExcel provides some methods for reducing memory usage (at a cost in speed), it still uses memory, whether reading and/or writing

Comment: "usage (at a cost in speed)," => that would be no problem, import will only be pushed manually. so if it would take more time, i will rise PHP timeout a little bit.

Comment: Typically, I'd be inclined to move such processes to back-end tasks, running them as a cron task from the command line, or via a job queue system, where the default time is normally unlimited

Comment: But where can we add cache method, should it be added in own script or in a part of classes? Thank you.

Comment: The PHPExcel library provides variou caching methods; your script has to indicate which one you want to use (as described in the documentation that I linked you) otherwise it defaults to using standard PHP memory

Comment: Ok we now tried to add caching, now it works with odt file but not with xls File: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 80 bytes) in /includes/PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/CachedObjectStorage/DiscISAM.php on line 67 - Do you know what to do?

Comment: No I don't know what to do, try using the more efficient caching options like SQLite pperhaps...... other than what I've already suggested..... I'm afraid I'm not Gandalf or Happy Potter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd download a fresh source from https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/releases/tag/1.8.1

or the latest files from github @ https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

as neither of those include that line/function you reference.